# Ito processes and Martingales

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

We consider a stochastic differential equation:

$dx\left(  t\right)  =f\left(  x\left(  t\right)  \right)  dt+\sigma\left(
x\left(  t\right)  \right)  dW\left(  t\right)$

where $x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $\sigma:\mathbb{R}%
^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. If $g:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow
\mathbb{R}$ is twice continuously differentiable. I have some problems with
the following:

(i) Is $g_{x}\left(  x\left(  t\right)  \right)
^{T}\sigma\left(  x\left(  t\right)  \right)  $ a martingale? ($g_{x}$
represents the gradient of $g$ with respect to $x$).

(ii) If
$g_{x}\left(  x\left(  t\right)  \right)  ^{T}\sigma\left(  x\left(  t\right)
\right)  $ is Ito-integrable, the random process $f_{x}\left(  x\left(
t\right)  \right)  \sigma\left(  x\left(  t\right)  \right)  $ is mean-square
integrable from $0$ to $t$?

Comment: Just asking : which textbook(notes) have you read on the subject, and is this an exercise in that book?

Comment: I am reading a book by Xuerong Mao and some notes by Geering et al. from ETH Zurich. It is not really an exercise in any book, just a question that occurred to me.

Comment: I can't see why either of these is true. Have you seen specific examples of this phenomena holding for certain $g,\sigma$? (Maybe in simple cases?)

Comment: I think $M\left(  t\right)  =\int_{0}^{t}g_{x}^{T}\left(  x\left(  s\right)
\right)  \sigma\left(  x\left(  s\right)  \right)  dW\left(  s\right)  $ is a
local martingale. In order to get a martingale it is sufficient to have

$E\sup_{t\in\left[  0,T\right]  }\left\Vert M\left(  t\right)  \right\Vert
<\infty\text{ for all }T$

I do not see which conditions to impose to $g$ and $\sigma$ for this.